# problem in bevel while using box cutter

Tags: add-on, bevel

when I cut my cube using box cutter addon and bevel it , its not bevel with equal edges can someone help me please I am struggle for last two days why it look like this ….

[image]

Comment: could you [add a gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers?r=SearchResults) of how you end up with your result? Then someone (who has the addon as it is paid) can more easily take a look. Thanks

Comment: ok I will post it